# How to make cooldowns use the exceptions given

Tags: python, discord.py

What i am specifically looking for is that i want is for the exception to be thrown on ("you must mention someone to x") and for the exception of if the person isn't in the guild to throw that message instead of using the cooldown.

```
@tasks.loop(count=1)
async def load_interaction_commands(self):
    """ Load interaction commands. """
    self.bot.interaction_commands = []
    cooldown = commands.Cooldown(1, 600, commands.BucketType.user)
    mapping = commands.CooldownMapping(cooldown)
    for cmd, aliases in COMMANDS.items():
        async def interaction_callback(cls, ctx, user: discord.Member):
            if not user:
                await ctx.send(f"You must mention someone to {ctx.command}.")
            elif user == ctx.author:
                await ctx.send("You can't {} yourself, silly!".format(ctx.command.name))
            elif not discord.utils.find(lambda m: m.id == user.id, ctx.guild.members):
                await ctx.send("you cant {} someone not in the server silly!")
            else:
                await cls.interact(ctx, user)

        interaction_callback = commands.command(name=cmd, aliases=aliases)(interaction_callback)
        interaction_callback._buckets = mapping
        interaction_callback.__commands_cooldown__ = cooldown
        interaction_callback.cog = self
        self.bot.add_command(interaction_callback)
        self.bot.interaction_commands.append(interaction_callback)
```